# Routing non-CRUD method to API Endpoint

Tags: c#, api

Please, help me with my home project:
I can call all CRUD methods without problems, but I don’t know how to direct non-CRUD API calls to the proper endpoint.

Tried this:

```
var rentalEvent = rest.GetSingle<RentalEvent>($"api/rentalevent/boo/{licensePlate}");
```

To reach this:

```
[Route("/boo")]
[HttpGet("{licensePlate}")]
public RentalEvent GetGetRentalEventByLicensePlate(string licensePlate)
{
        return new RentalEvent { RenterId = 88 }; //mock return class
}
```

The Controller class’ attributes are set up as:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")] 
[ApiController]
```

Comment: Try removing the `Route` attribute from the action, and using `[HttpGet("boo/{licensePlate}")]` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen the Route attribute along with the HttpGet attribute

Comment: You are using a controller and everything is a request/response.  The end points should always be the same URL. Every request/response should be sending a class object like <RentalEvent>

Comment: @Jonesopolis : Route and HttpGet are allowable.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2?force_isolation=true

Comment: *I've never seen the Route attribute along with the HttpGet attribute* - i find it very handy to not use Route at all. When someone says "the /api/whatever/get/account/1" endpoint is crashing, I can just Ctrl-F for `api/whatever/get/account` and get to the handling method. It's a lot more of a nuisance if the route is broken up across multiple attributes, and especially if some of it is hidden inside a `[controller]` placeholder

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. I'm digesting / testing the answers. Will accept the one that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route specified in `HttpGet` with overrides what you've set before in the `Route` attribute. Try one of the following:

Use only `HttpGet` with the whole Route:

```cs
[HttpGet("boo/{licensePlate}")]
public RentalEvent GetGetRentalEventByLicensePlate(string licensePlate)
{
        return new RentalEvent { RenterId = 88 }; //mock return class
}
```

Or use `HttpGet` without an argument and put the whole route in the `Route` attribute:

```cs
[Route("boo/{licensePlate}")]
[HttpGet]
public RentalEvent GetGetRentalEventByLicensePlate(string licensePlate)
{
        return new RentalEvent { RenterId = 88 }; //mock return class
}
```

For more info, see [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Best to just have the Api route defined in one place.

```
[HttpGet("/boo")]
public RentalEvent GetGetRentalEventByLicensePlate(string licensePlate)
{
        return new RentalEvent { RenterId = 88 }; //mock return class
}
```

For a get request a string value should generally be used as an optional parameter in the query.

```
api/rentalevent/boo?licensePlate=mylicense
```

Putting an arbitrary string in the route definition implies a different endpoint rather than a different parameter value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved it! I can only accept one answer unfortunately.